# Make mouse cursor go pass screen?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager

I'm trying to find a way to allow my mouse cursor to go a few (3-4) pixels pass the actual screen border.

I'm trying to do this in order to allow resizing maximized windows in certain window managers.

It there a way to make the mouse cursor area 3008x2008, if my resolution is 3000x2000?

I'm on X on Ubuntu Linux.